# mysql query count fields

Tags: mysql, join, count

I've got some trouble with a sql query if someone can help me will be brilliant. So I have **students, participation, courses, places, student_to_courses** these tables. I need to get all students in particular course and I'm doing with this query

```
select 
  s.name as student_name, c.name as course_name, p.name as place_name
from 
  student_to_courses s2c, 
  students_participation sp, 
  students s,
  courses c,
  places p

where 
s.id = s2c.participation_id AND
s.id = sp.profile_id AND 
c.id = s2c.course_id AND
p.id = c.place_id = p.id AND
s2c.course_id = 1
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea6610/2)

but I need to count how many times the student has been in particular place, something like this **student_name, course_name, place_name, | 3 |**. Now I'm doing it with another query which I call each time in my loop. But I was wondering if there is a way to do it just with single query. Thanks in advance to everyone who would like to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) and then GROUP BY the remaining columns:

```
select s.name as student_name, 
       c.name as course_name, 
       p.name as place_name, 
       count(*)
from students s
inner join student_to_courses s2c on s.id = s2c.participation_id
inner join courses c on c.id = s2c.course_id
inner join places p on p.id = c.place_id
inner join students_participation sp on s.id = sp.profile_id
where s2c.course_id = 1
group by s.name,c.name,p.name
```

I also changed your joins to explicit joins, since it is much easier to read an less error prone.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6357b6/3)</kbd>

Comment: wow that was quick, yeah this should work, but there is a one more thing which I forgot I need to add to my count only those who are already finished the course so when I add unix_timestamp(c.end) < time() won't show the result, because is in inner join, and I need to count actually students id not participation id, that's really confusing me.

Comment: I'm not sure i understood if you want a left join or to keep the inner join and count only some. If it is the second one, try doing `SUM(CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(c.end) < time() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` instead of COUNT(*).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
  s.name as student_name, c.name as course_name, 
  p.name as place_name, count(*) qtd
from 
  student_to_courses s2c, 
  students_participation sp, 
  students s,
  courses c,
  places p
where 
   s.id = s2c.participation_id AND
   s.id = sp.profile_id AND 
   c.id = s2c.course_id AND
   p.id = c.place_id = p.id AND
   s2c.course_id = 1
group by s.name, c.name, p.name
```

The `count(*)` is an [AGGREGATE FUNCTION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) See this link to understand.